# Improving the Cauchy's bound on the absolute values of the roots of the monic polynomial $x^n=m \times \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots, solution-verification

Given a polynomial $x^n=m \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k$ (for all $m,n \in \mathbb{N}, m \geq 2,n\geq 2$), the numerical computation of roots for different $n$ and $m$ shows, that the absolute values of roots are *strictly less* than $m + 1$. The [Cauchy's bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_properties_of_polynomial_roots#Lagrange's_and_Cauchy's_bounds) gives a non-strict bound for the given polynomial: the absolute values of roots are *less or equal* to $m+1$.

I have come up with the approach for showing the strict inequality, and would like to ask, if my approach is valid?
Below is a description of my approach.

---

If we show that the roots don't belong to the complex circle with radius $m+1$, then in combination with the Cauchy's bound we will obtain a strict inequality.

As far as $x=1$ is not a root of this polynomial, we can transform the polynomial as follows:

$$
x^n - m \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k = x^n - m \cdot {x^n-1 \over x - 1} = 0
$$

So, equivalently, we need to consider the roots of the polynomial: $x^n \cdot ((m+1) - x) - m = 0$.

For the sake of contradiction let's assume, that $x =(m+1) \cdot e^{i \phi}$ (for some $\phi \in \mathbb{R}$) is a root of the polynomial $x^n \cdot ((m+1) - x) - m = 0$.

After doing the substitution we obtain:

$$
(m+1)^n \cdot e^{i n \phi} \cdot ((m+1) - (m+1) \cdot e^{i \phi}) = m \iff \\
\iff (m+1)^{n+1} \cdot e^{i n \phi} \cdot (1 - e^{i \phi}) = m \iff \\
\iff e^{i n \phi} \cdot (1 - e^{i \phi}) = {m \over (m+1)^{n+1}} \iff \\
\iff e^{i n \phi} - e^{i (n+1) \phi} = {m \over (m+1)^{n+1}}
$$

Using the trigonometric form of complex numbers we can rewrite the latter equality as follows:

$$
\left( cos(n\phi) - cos((n+1)\phi) \right) - i \cdot \left( sin(n\phi) - sin((n + 1)\phi) \right) = {m \over (m+1)^{n+1}}
$$

As far as the imaginary part on the left hand side is $0$ we have a following system:

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
 sin(n\phi) - sin((n+1)\phi) &= 0 \\ 
 cos(n\phi) - cos((n+1)\phi) &= {m \over (m+1)^{n+1}}
\end{aligned}\right.
$$

Using the [sum-to-product trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) we can rewrite the system as follows:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
 2 \cdot cos \left({2n + 1 \over 2} \phi \right) \cdot sin \left( - {\phi \over 2} \right) &= 0 \\ 
 -2 \cdot sin \left({2n + 1 \over 2} \phi \right) \cdot sin \left( - {\phi \over 2} \right) &= {m \over (m+1)^{n+1}}
\end{aligned}\right.
$$

Looking at the first equation: $2 \cdot cos \left({2n + 1 \over 2} \phi \right) \cdot sin \left( - {\phi \over 2} \right)$ we conclude that some of its multipliers should be $0$. So, we have two cases:

- Case 1: $sin \left( - {\phi \over 2} \right) = 0$. In this case the second equation shows a **contradiction**:

$$
-2 \cdot sin \left({2n + 1 \over 2} \phi \right) \cdot sin \left( - {\phi \over 2} \right) = 0 \neq {m \over (m+1)^{n+1}}
$$

- Case 2: $cos \left({2n + 1 \over 2} \phi \right) = 0$. In this case we can see that: $\phi = {2k + 1 \over 2n + 1} \pi$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Let's substitute $\phi$ into the second equation:

$$
-2 \cdot sin \left({2n + 1 \over 2} \cdot {2k + 1 \over 2n + 1} \pi \right) \cdot sin \left( - {1 \over 2} \cdot {2k + 1 \over 2n + 1} \pi \right) = {m \over (m+1)^{n+1}} \iff \\
\iff sin \left({2k + 1 \over 2 \cdot (2n + 1)} \pi \right) = {m \over 2 \cdot (m+1)^{n+1}}
$$

So, from the second equation we have obtained the equation $sin(a \cdot \pi) = b$, where $a$ and $b$ are rational numbers ($a={2k + 1 \over 2 \cdot (2n + 1)}$ and $b={m \over (m+1)^{n+1}}$). Furthermore, in case if $m \geq 2, n \geq 2$ we see that $b \not \in \{ 0, \pm 1, \pm {1 \over 2}\}$. In this case, we have a **contradiction** with the [Niven's Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NivensTheorem.html) (that states, that if $sin(a \cdot \pi) = b$ and $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$, then the sine takes only the values $0, \pm 1, \pm {1 \over 2}$).

So, we see that the original assumption (that $(m+1) \cdot e^{i \phi}$ is a root of the polynomial) leads to the contradiction. Consequently, $(m+1) \cdot e^{i \phi}$ can't be a root of the polynomial.

In combination with the Cauchy's bound we have a strict bound on the absolute values of roots: the roots are *strictly less* than $m + 1$.

---

So, I would like to know if my approach is valid?
And, the second question: if there are any simpler approaches that allow to obtain a strict bound in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, I would like to know if my approach is valid?

Your proof seems to be good, I could not find an error. It should work even for $m \ge 1$ and $n \ge 1$.

> And, the second question: if there are any simpler approaches that allow to obtain a strict bound in this case?

Yes: If $x$ with $|x| > 1$ is a root of that polynomial then
$$
 |x|^n \le m\left(1 + |x| + \ldots + |x|^{n-1} \right) = m \frac{|x|^n-1}{|x|-1} \, .
$$
Multiplication with the (positive) number $(|x|-1)/|x|^n$ gives
$$
 |x| -1 \le m \frac{|x|^n-1}{|x|^n} < m
$$
and therefore the strict inequality $|x| < m +1$.

This also works for all positive real numbers $m$, not only for integers.

---

More generally, an inspection of the proof of Cauchy's bound (e.g. the one [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/320592331_On_the_Cauchy_Bound_for_the_Roots_of_Polynomials)) shows that if
$$
h = \max\{ |a_0|, |a_1|, \ldots, |a_{n-1}| \} > 0
$$
then all roots of
$$
 x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + a_1 x + x_0 = 0
$$
satisfy the strict inequality $|x| < 1 + h$.

Comment: Thank you Martin for checking the proof, and for sharing the shorter proof and the clarification about the Cauchy's bound!